# How to reject accessing a user to a custom file in php

Tags: php

I've got a question.. I have 3 main files on my root directory which looks like this:

```
1- index.php
2- login.php 
3- dashboard.php
```

Basically If a user goes to my site ,he will redirected automatically to `index.php` file which contains a captcha code & if he enters the correct code ,he will redirected to the `login.php` file. So he can use his information to sign in to the `dashboard.php` file.

The problem is ,he can access to the login page without entering any code at index page. for example he can go to this url and access the login page manually:

**http://www.example.com/login.php**

Is there a way to reject and deny the accessing of a user from a custom page ? So in this situation ,he MUST access the index page and after that he will be redirected to the login page.

It would be very helpful if you know how to solve this question ...  Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the login page, check for a session variable that you set in the index page after correct code insertion. If the variable is ok, go on. If the variable is not ok, redirect the user to index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this at the top of each of my pages. If the session variable is not set, provide a link to the login page (this could be a redirect if you want), and do not display anything else. If the session variable has been set, meaning the user is logged in, then proceed with displaying the page.

```
<?php

//start the session
session_start(); 

//If the user is not logged in: provide a link to the login page. 
if (!isset($_SESSION["CurrentUser"])){ 
    ?><a href="login.php"' >Click here to Login</a><?php
    exit(); //Do not display the rest of the page. This will stop the PHP from executing. Important!

//If the user is logged in: show them the page  
}else{
    require_once('top.php');
  //in addition to including top.php, the code below this line will execute.
}


?>
```

On your login page, wherever you do the authentication piece, just add this upon successful login.

```
 $_SESSION["CurrentUser"] = $username
```

Answer (score 0):

on each file except the index,, check for the session,,create the session into the index.php, so the other file will catch the session, if there is no session setted, then show message,,,

```
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['session_name'])){
 echo  '<script language="javascript">';
 echo  'alert("Please Insert The Code")';
 echo  '</script>';
 echo("<script>location.href = 'index.php';</script>");
 }
```